# How to call upon a Binary Search Tree in an algorithm

Tags: python, dictionary

I am attempting to create a simple version of spell check which takes a .txt file and compares whether each word is found in the dictionary or not. I have established functions that turn .txt files into lists and the dictionary into a list, but I am struggling calling upon my sorted binary search tree for the dictionary in my spell check function. Here is the class for BinarySearchTree followed by my spell checker function

```
class BinarySearchTree:

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

    def insert(self,val):
        if self.root == None:
            self.root = BinaryNode(val)
        else:
            self.recursive_insert(root,val)

    def recursive_insert(self,parent,val):
        if parent.data < val:
            if parent.right != None:
                self.recursive_insert(parent.right,val)
            else:
                parent.right = BinaryNode(val)
        else:
            if parent.left != None:
                self.recursive_insert(parent.left,val)
            else:
                parent.left = BinaryNode(val)

    def dictionary_insert(self,text):
        for word in text:
            self.insert(word)

    def search(self,val):
        if self.recursive_search(self.root,val) != None:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def recursive_search(self,parent,val):
        if parent.data == val:
            return parent
        elif parent.data > val:
            return self.recursive_search(parent.left,val)
        else:
            return self.recursive_search(parent.right,val)
```

Here is my spell checker function:

```
def spell_checker(text):

    N = len(text)
    misspelled = 0
    for i in range(N):
        if BinarySearchTree().search(text[i]) == True:
            misspelled = misspelled
        else:
            misspelled = misspelled + 1
            print text[i]
    if misspelled == 0:
        print "There are no spelling errors!"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean "struggling"? Are you getting errors? Unexpected outputs?

Comment: I am getting errors such as NoneType' object has no attribute 'data when my recursive_search function is called through the BinarySearchTree.search reference I make in spell_checker

Comment: Something to consider, then: suppose you call recursive_search with a word that isn't in your tree? What will it happen when it gets down to a leaf node that has no children and `parent.data` is not equal to `val`?

Comment: Your tree never actually loads any data

Comment: Could that be fixed with another statement such as if not parent: return None ? for the case where leaf node has no children

Comment: Yes! That's exactly the thing to do. There may be other problems with the code, but one of the most important things with a recursive algorithm is to make sure that the _termination step_ handles both success and failure correctly.

Comment: How could my tree be adjusted to load data if you do not mind me asking?

Comment: I have added that information in my answer

Comment: @Izkata and @jonrsharpe are also correct: calling `BinarySearchTree().search(text[i])` creates a new (empty) binary search tree, and then attempts to call the `search` method on it, which is guaranteed to fail on an empty tree. As @jonrsharpe suggested, you must save your new tree in a variable like `bst`, call `bst.dictionary_insert` to make sure it has words in it, and then call `bst.search` to see if the tree has the desired words in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you first call `recursive_search`, you pass `self.root` as `parent`. However, in `__init__`, `self.root` was set to `None`. Therefore trying to access `parent.data` gives you an error, as `None.data` doesn't exist. You need to do a `dictionary_insert`, passing in a list of valid words, as part of your setup procedure, so that the tree actually has words in it:

```
dct = BinarySearchTree()
dct.dictionary_insert(valid_word_list)
```

You will also need to correct the last line of `insert`:

```
self.recursive_insert(self.root, val)
```

Comment: I have attempted the changes to my set up and they work. I am unsure about my insert function. I will have to look into that further

Answer (score 0):

Just to fill this out in an answer:

The `recursive_search` call doesn't handle failure correctly:

```
def recursive_search(self,parent,val):
    if parent.data == val:
        return parent
    elif parent.data > val:
        return self.recursive_search(parent.left,val)
    else:
        return self.recursive_search(parent.right,val)
```

If the word isn't found in the tree at all, eventually this will be called with the `parent` argument set to `None`, and the statement `if parent.data == val:` will throw a `NoneType` exception.

The solution here is to return `None` when `parent == None`:

```
def recursive_search(self,parent,val):
    if parent == None:
        return None
    if parent.data == val:
        return parent
    elif parent.data > val:
        return self.recursive_search(parent.left,val)
    else:
        return self.recursive_search(parent.right,val)
```